# Log-in query in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question with SQL query that I can't figure out.
I would like to know the users that are **currently** logged in to the system.
The data of the logging system is listed below.
My logic says that I would need to find Name that has Action_type=51 but doesn't have Action_type=52 or Action_type=53 following.

I've tried lots of different queries, but none of them got me the information that I need.
Here's my table:

**Login table**

```
|ID       |Action_type |        Date_time         | Name   |
|        1|51          |2017-11-06 17:13:55.227   | John   |
|        2|51          |2017-11-06 17:16:00.331   | Mary   |
|        3|53          |2017-11-06 17:45:55.227   | John   |
|        4|52          |2017-11-06 18:33:15.727   | Mary   |
|        5|51          |2017-11-07 10:13:49.558   | John   |
|        6|51          |2017-11-07 11:43:08.691   | Bonnie |
```

Action_types are defined by
**51 -** Log in
**52 -** Log out
**53 -** Log out(timed out)

////EDIT:

```
Select * From login_table lt
Where date_time = (Select Max(date_time)
             From login_table  
             Where action_type = action_type and action_type=51)
```

This is what I figured out, but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for, as it only returns the last one(max),  but I still cant figure out how I can display all of the connect users right now.

Comment: Is this a homework question? In any case you need to take a look at [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) function.

Comment: Hi, Alex. No it's not homework question. I need the result of that query to be sent to my email automatically afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Use [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql)

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #login_table( ID INT, Action_type INT, Date_time DATETIME, Name VARCHAR( 20 ))
INSERT INTO #login_table
VALUES
( 1,51,'2017-11-06 17:13:55.227', 'John   ' ),
( 2,51,'2017-11-06 17:16:00.331', 'Mary   ' ),
( 3,53,'2017-11-06 17:45:55.227', 'John   ' ),
( 4,52,'2017-11-06 18:33:15.727', 'Mary   ' ),
( 5,51,'2017-11-07 10:13:49.558', 'John   ' ),
( 6,51,'2017-11-07 11:43:08.691', 'Bonnie ' ),
( 6,53,'2017-11-09 11:43:08.691', 'Bonnie ' )
```

The query should look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ( CASE WHEN LEAD(Action_type,1, 0) OVER( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date_time ) IN( 52, 53 ) THEN 'LoggedOff' ELSE 'LoggedIn' END ) AS UserStatus
    FROM #login_table
) AS a
WHERE UserStatus = 'LoggedIn'
    AND Action_Type = 51
    -- Optional cut off filter
    -- AND Date_time > DATEADD( DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

Output:

```
ID          Action_type Date_time               Name                 UserStatus
----------- ----------- ----------------------- -------------------- ----------
5           51          2017-11-07 10:13:49.557 John                 LoggedIn
```

Comment: Mary logged in at 2017-11-06 17:16:00.331 and out at 2017-11-06 18:33:15.727 so she isn't currently logged in, unless im missing something

Comment: @Zulatin, thanks for spotting this. I have added `AND ActionType = 51` to `WHERE`

Comment: I tested this, It returned over 250 rows dating back to October. It shows all log-ins by user. Unfortunately it didn't help me right now. Thank You for your time!

Comment: if you add actiontype to inner query it works for me in the small sample you gave us. Did you include that part?

Comment: @Kaspar, You can add a date filter to cut off old records. Updated question to show an example

Comment: Thank's for your response. Yes I added them both, limited the rows down a little bit. But the thing is, it displays all the log-ins of today, but not the ones that are currently logged-in. 



For an example: Account John has logged in 4 times today, so all the 4 rows have different ID's and different  date_time's. There are 8 separate accounts that have logged in today already, each one 4 times, so 8*4 = 32 rows are displayed

Comment: @Kaspar, I have just tested my query (as posted) with sample data and it only returns people that are currently logged in. Have added sample data to my answer and generated output

Comment: @Alex if i only added actiontype = 51 to the outer part it would be marked as wrong syntax because it was missing column actiontype. I only added the column, not the condition